# Ajax me imprime todo el código PHP en vez de el echo en mi servidor, pero en local no sucede

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hago un llamado de una función que utiliza ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../log/cursos.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        hola: hola
    }

})
    .done(function (respuesta) {
        alert(respuesta);
        $("#OpcionesCurso").html(respuesta);
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("Error: SQL not working")
    });
```

Luego entra al archivo php

```
<?php
$curso = $_POST['hola'];
$salida = "";


$salida .= "<datalist id='datalistOptions'>";
$salida .= "<option value=" . $curso . ">";
$salida .= "</datalist>";
echo "$salida";
?>
```

Pero la respuesta que me entrega el ajax es literalmente el código entero de PHP en vez de el echo $salida, alguna solución? Solo ocurre en el servidor, en Local no me sucede.

Comment: ¿Estás revisando la consola del navegador? ¿Algún error allí? Es imprescindible activar la consola cuando estás depurando código Javascript.

Comment: Si, revisé y no hay problemas. Lo que pasa es que me está tomando php pero no como un archivo php, o eso es lo que creo.

Comment: ¿Puedes abrir directamente `cursos.php` en el navegador (sin AJAX)? ¿Sigue apareciendo el código PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que `PHP` es un lenguaje de programacion interpretado, pero para poder correr necesita de un servidor que lo soporte por ejemplo `apache`, y que ademas debes de tener tu extension de archivo seteada como `.php`, hay archivos que aunque les cambien la extension su tipo seguira siendo otro, por este motivo trata de crear un nuevo archivo y guardalo estrictamente con extension `.php`.

Ademas, recuerda que **NO** puedes simplemente hacer la petición al archivo y ya sin usar como dije anteriormente un servidor que te compile `PHP`, pues enrealidad `PHP` **no** es reconocido por los navegadores de manera directa.

Por lo tanto si intentas abrir un archivo `.php` directamente en el navegador sin que pase por un servidor que lo compile te va a mostrar solo el texto del `php` y no va a realizar lo que tu deseas.

Si en tu servidor final tienes ese problema pero no en local, quiere decir que `PHP` no esta interpretando el codigo, haz visto si tu servidor soporta `PHP`?, si es así, te aseguraste de colocar tu proyecto dentro de la carpeta que hostea tus proyectos?

En algunos servidores es `htdocs` en otros es la carpeta `www`, asegurate de que tienes tu proyecto dentro de la carpeta `htdocs` o `www`.

Como ultima nota deberías intentar crear un archivo `php` en el servidor y dirigirte hacia el en el navegador usando la direccion de tu servidor, en el coloca el codigo mas basico posible:

```
<?php
   echo "Hello world!";
?>
```

Si el resultado es un mitico "hello world" entonces hay algo que tienes mal en tu otro archivo, en caso de que en esta ocasion tambien se te imprima el codigo entero y no un simple "hello world", entonces hay cuatro opciones posibles:

1. El servidor que usas no soporta PHP
2. El servidor que usas soporta PHP pero no esta activado por defecto
3. No tienes el proyecto en el servidor en la carpeta adecuada, carpeta en la cual sera renderizado tu codigo php sin problemas.
4. Tu archivo puede tener un nombre como: `"cursos.php"`, pero enrealidad su tipo integro no es `PHP` si no `HTML`, y por eso no esta siendo procesado, pues esta siendo directamente utilizado por el navegador sin pasar por la interpretación de `PHP` ya que es detectado como un archivo `HTML`.

Comment: Más que compilado es interpretado no?

Comment: @BetaM Ohhh... rayos!, como pude colocar que era compilado ._., cierto, es interpretado ya lo corrijo